# What is this plant (looking like oenothera?) with creamy flowers?

Tags: identification

Zone 7a, continental Europe.

What is this plant doing in my garden? I did not plant it.

The plant in question is in the middle: (to the top and right are two echinaceas, to the left is a part of viburnum bodnantense, and a stump of a plum)

[image]

More details:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Height 50 cm (now, seems to be growing)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like Evening Lychnis (also known as White Catchfly and a host of other common names) - Silene latifolia v. alba, maybe Silene noctiflora - probably the former. One identifier is the way two or more buds erupt from a single node. It also has a rather ungainly habit (to my eyes, it looks like a weed).

Photos to compare. Buds from a single node: https://pics.davesgarden.com/pics/2005/06/13/kniphofia/ce04c8.jpg

Habit: https://img.plantis.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Silenelatifolia.jpg

In flower, S. latifolia can get about 40-80 cm tall; it's usually an annual, but if happy can be a short-lived perennial.

Comment: You are fantasic!